# Cannot connect to Metro (Running React Native App in Expo)

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner who just learn React Native.

I am facing an issues in running my React Native Application from Android Studio Emulator by using Expo. My android emulator keep disconnecting and it prompting an error message saying that "Cannot connect to Metro".

Here is the screenshot from Android Emulator for the error message. May I ask how to solve this issue?

[Error message from Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv7cL.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround for this is to install adb tools via brew and then connect it to metro via `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in a second terminal. When the answer is 8081 you are connected...
If somebody has a solution to finally resolve this I would also be happy to not use this all the time.